# In VS Code is there any shortcut to make {% %} for Django?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there any keyboard shortcut or extension that contains a shortcut where {% %} is automatically written out, and preferably the cursor is placed inside? Just starting with learning Django and it seems like you'll be using this enough that a shortcut would be useful.

Comment: Django snippets extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the Django extension by Baptiste. Give it a whirl:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=batisteo.vscode-django

Answer (score 0):

In the Django Extension from Baptiste Darthenay you can type **variable** to generate {{ }} and **tag** to generate {% %}.